# Why is my 2008 honda civic coupe clicking?

Tags: honda, noise, locks, key, clicking

My 2008 honda civic clicks a fixed number of times when you turn the key on, not when you start it.
It also happens when you lock or unlock the doors.
I don't think it's the ac actuator because it dosen't click or anything when I change from hot to cold or from floor to defrost.
If you have any idea what this could be please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Fuel pump relay?

Comment: You seem to imply this clicking is related to the heater system?